# Smooth wood texture

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Which shaders can I add to a smooth wood texture to make it more realistic? 
I have used diffuse and glossy shaders together with mix shaders. 
What else can I add

Comment: Do you have a reference image of what you are going for? Diffuse and glossy is a logical step, without seeing your goal and current result I can really only say maybe try tweaking the factor on your mix shader, and checking that smooth shading is enabled as that will make a difference in your render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shaders you want depend on the exact usecase. I (personally) would use glossy and diffuse. I take it that you aren't using a **normalmap** as you say that your texture is flat. It could possibly be very useful.

Normalmaps basically **tell what kinds of little bumps there are in a surface** (or to put it more technically, they vary the orientation of the surface normals for angle of incidence calculations. This then affects lambertian diffuse to fake shadows.).

## Begin tl;dr

If you look at one (image shamelessly stolen from wikipedia) the idea becomes more obvious:

[image: Left: 3D-model, center: normalmap, right: normalmap applied to a flat surface]

(Left: 3D-model, center: normalmap, right: normalmap applied to a flat surface)

The normalmap uses colors to describe the orientation of the surface (red: right, green: up, blue: down).

If you want to get really technical, Wikipedia is your friend: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping

## End tl;dr

Andrew Price made a good **tutorial on Cycles shaders** a while back (see here: http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-realistic-materials-with-cycles/.) If you scroll down, you can find his **wooden floor material**.

For more info about shaders, **I'd reccomend you to consult this** (Andrew again):
http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/cycles-shader-encyclopedia/

For material inputs, refer to this (Even more Andrew Price):
http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/cycles-input-encyclopedia/

I sincerely hope this helps.